# A story puzzle for you

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

My brother loves numbers. He likes to pick a number, reflect, and enjoy its presence.

He picked a number and asked me to guess it. I guessed random numbers for twenty minutes.

I never got it right.

He said he would cut it in half and put it on this stack exchange website. I said, puzzling?

He said yes.

I searched the website for another twenty minutes and, lo, and behold I finally found his number.

Now it is your turn. I've given you everything you need. So, go, and find the number.

Comment: rot13(40? Lbh zragvba 20 va gur dhrfgvba gjb gvzrf naq unys bs 40 vf gjragl, naq vg vf ba chmmyvat fgnpx rkpunatr. Gur BC unf nyfb tvira rirelguvat lbh arrq, gur gjragl, juvpu orpbzrf sbegl.)

Comment: @Duck Nice Guess, but that is unintentional. 20 minutes is arbitrary!

Comment: @Duck What sort of code is that?

Comment: Is this number findable on this specific site, or is it on all SE sites in some specific place?

Comment: @Stormblessed It is rot13. Go to rot13.com to decode it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the answer

> 8? When the '8' is cut in half, it looks like the Puzzling Stack Exchange logo.

Comment: I like this, especially since rot13(gur jbeq "ersyrpg" jnf va gur chmmyr, naq jura lbh ersyrpg gur ybtb, lbh trg gur qvtvg rvtug).

Comment: Correct!. Well done. Also, rot13( vs lbh ghea gur grkg bs gur fgbel vagb PFI, gurer vf n zrffntr va gur frpbaq pbyhza (hfvat gur jbeq ersrypg)).